# Java RecyclerView adapter incorrectly coloring 14th item specifically, regardless of variable values

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a leaderboard that colors your name depending on your rank. For every 10 € spent, there is a new color. The last rank is a gradient color. It colors everything as it should, except for the 14th item (position 13). It gives that one the gradient color regardless of rank, name, number of items or anything else.
Here is MyAdapter:

```
package com.miskolin.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    List<Item> items;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.user.setText(items.get(position).getUser());
        holder.total.setText(items.get(position).getTotalSpent());
        Integer rank = items.get(position).getLeadersRank();
        int[][] rankColors = {
                {
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank0),  // Rank 0
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank1),  // Rank 1
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank2),  // Rank 2
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank3),  // Rank 3
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank4),  // Rank 4
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank5),  // Rank 5
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank6),  // Rank 6
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank7) , // Rank 7
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank8)   // Rank 8
                },
                {
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank9c1),
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank9c2),
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Rank9c3)
                }
        };

        if (rank >= rankColors[0].length) {
            Log.d("Debug", "Using LinearGradient for item at position " + position);
            TextPaint paint = holder.user.getPaint();
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 100, 3, 20, rankColors[1], null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            holder.user.setTextColor(rankColors[0][0]);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < rankColors[0].length; i++) {
                if (rank.equals(i)) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Using Color for item at position " + position);
                    holder.user.setTextColor(rankColors[0][i]);
                    Log.d("color", holder.user.getText() + " " + Integer.toHexString(rankColors[0][i]));
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Here is MyViewHolder:

```
package com.miskolin.app;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView user,total;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userView);
        total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
    }
}
```

So I played around with the recyclerview margin_bottom and found that the position of the incorrectly colored item is somehow related to the height of the recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/miskolin_leaderboard_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Graphs">



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/baseline_circle_24"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
        android:text="Lestvica"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#B6B3A7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crown"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/leaderboard"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/crown" />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/main"
        android:layout_below="@id/crown"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This setup now incorrectly colors the 15th item

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset the shader once it is set. During binding, you will need to touch all values changed in the binding since view holders and their item views are reused. Since you don't reset the shader, the previous value will hold during all rebindings. This is a common problem (not resetting values during rebinding.)

See [Paint#setShader()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#setShader(android.graphics.Shader)) about how to reset the shader.